# How can I automatically detect what control paint event I'm using?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have for example `Form1` paint event:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     TextDrawer draw = new TextDrawer(e.Graphics,this,8.25);
}
```

In the new class `TextDrawer` I need to enter the control name in this case its form1 so I type:

This is the new class:

```
class TextDrawer
{
        private readonly Graphics g;
        private readonly Control c ;
        private readonly double font_size;

        public TextDrawer(Graphics g,Control c,
                          double font_size)
        {
            this.g = g;
            this.c = c;
            this.font_size = font_size;
        }

        public void DrawText(string text,Color pen_color,Color brushes_color, Point point1, Point point2, Point point3)
        {
            c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily.Name, (float)font_size);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(brushes_color);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(pen_color, 10f))
            {
                Point pt1 = point1;
                Point pt2 = point2;
                g.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
            }

            g.DrawString(text,
                    c.Font, brush, point3);
        }
    }
```

I want to make somehow that once i type inside a paint event of any control is its form1 pictureBox1 label any control that have a paint event once i make a new instance for the class for example:

```
TextDrawer draw = new TextDrawer(e.Graphics,8.25);
```

And the new class will detect/find automatic the control name so the user wont need to type in: this or pictureBox1 or label1...

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Your `TextDrawer` class takes a control as constructor argument. This has a "Name" and a "Text" property. Use whichever fits for your needs. What exactly do you want to do with the control name anyway? And do you really mean the control name or do you mean the control text?

Comment: This is what i mean : TextDrawer draw = new TextDrawer(e.Graphics,((Control)sender),8.25); And in the new class i can use this to change the current control properties. The idea is that now i can copy the whole code to another paint event of another control without the need to modify the control name. Not string name but the control "Name" . And this is working.

Comment: This is all rather a bad idea.  Especially the part where you reassign the control's Font property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example in the `TextChanged` event of the TextBox you can pass the `sender` argument as the Control.

```
private void YourTextBoxOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxTextChanged((TextBox)sender);
}

private void YourTextBoxTwo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxTextChanged((TextBox)sender);
}

private void TextBoxTextChanged(TextBox tb)
{
    var draw = new TextDrawer(tb, 8.25);
    //Do something
}
```